# ASP.NET MVC 3 JQuery Validation reset single field

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Unobtrusive validation with ASP.NET MVC3. The field validation is working fine however I need to clear an error on a field through code without removing the fields ability to still validate.

E.g. a user enters a value which is incorrect which displays and error message, they click a button which clears the error message. The user enters another incorrect value and the error message shows again.

I can only find a method to reset the whole form, not an individual fields

Answer (score 1):

This is definitively a hack, but it will work:

```
(function($, global) {
    global.hideError = function(selector) {
        if(!selector) throw 'Arugment cannot be null or undefined : "selector"';
        $(selector).removeClass('input-validation-error').next('span.field-validation-error').find('span').remove();
    };
})(jQuery, window);

//Use it like so
hideError('#Password');
```